# What do you call someone who defines and oversees the work required to complete a task?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or term that describes someone who takes a problem, lists out the steps or tasks required to solve the problem, and oversees the solution to the end.

E.g. Sally worked out all the details for this Sunday's migration, and listed what needs to be done. She is the ___.

Comment: She is the *project manager*? Also consider *task manager* and *architect*.

Comment: Also possibly *overseer* or *supervisor*. You need to clarify your question so that one synonym is obviously more appropriate than another.

Answer (score 0):

Sally is the "organizer" or "event organizer" because she has organized the details of the event, such as setting times and rules, and acquiring needed resources.

> n
>   The organizer of an event or activity is the person who makes sure that the necessary arrangements are made. 
>   Synonyms: planner, manager, administrator, supervisor 
>   [COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary (from Collins Dictionary Online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/organizer)

The term "event organizer" is a common job position you can see advertised. Both officially in terms of occupation and unofficially (eg., planning a family trip), the organizer is supposedly responsible for the successes or failures of whatever event we're talking about, or at least their actions contribute to the successes and failures.